# How to get a firebase refresh token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, refresh-token

In the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token below this sample request curl

```
curl 'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[REFRESH_TOKEN]'
```

it is mentioned that `In the example above, you would replace [API_KEY] with the Web API Key of your Firebase project, [REFRESH_TOKEN] with the Firebase refresh token.` I can get the API_KEY from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

BUT where do I get this **REFRESH_TOKEN** from?

---

**UPDATE:** just realized (after a good night sleep) I had the following already in my page

```
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebase);
...
auth.currentUser.getIdToken(false)
```

All I had to do was

```
auth.currentUser.refreshToken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `refresh_token` is already included in the authentication API call response (whether it is [SignInWithEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password), [AnonymousSignIn](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-anonymously), etc..).

You can consume this refresh token only **once** in order to get a new one.
It is your responsibility to save that `refresh_token` in order to consume it later.